# Why doesn't scanf put characters back on failing?

Tags: c, scanf

I know that `scanf` (and family) returns the number of arguments it successfully read. I also know that if it fails, the input remains untouched, so you can do stuff like this:

```
printf("%s", "Plese input a string or a float.\n");
float f;
char s[128];
if(scanf("%f", &f) == 1) {
    //do something to respond to user answering with a float. (1)
} else if(scanf("%127s", s)) {
    //do something to process the string. (2)
}
```

It turns out that `scanf` *does* mess with the input. I expect the scanf to try to read anything that matches `<float here>` and not do anything in case of a failure, but what happens instead, is `scanf` eating the input until whatever point it thinks is a good point to stop.

For example: If I input `1.2`, I end up in branch `(1)` and `f = 1.2` as expected.

If I input `text` the result is as expected, I end up in `(2)` and `s = "text"`.

However, if the input is `normal` the result is that I end up in `(2)` without any extra user input and the value of `s = "rmal"`. Why is `no` consumed is beyond me.

I am going to preemptively point out that, yes, I am using `fgets` instead of `scanf`, wherever possible, thank you for your suggestion.

The question remains the same: " *Why does scanf consume input even on failure?* "

Comment: "I also know that if it fails, the input remains untouched" - no, it doesn't. *Unread* input will remain untouched, though. Perhaps you were reading something about `sscanf`?

Comment: Note that if you have more than one conversion specification and the second one, say, fails, then the third and subsequent conversions won't be attempted. Characters other than white space and conversion specifications must match too and failure will be reported unless they appear after the last conversion specification.

Comment: Also, `scanf()` uses one character of pushback, which is all the standard guarantees via `ungetc()`.

Comment: @trentcl Eh, I guess I shouldn't have said it that way. I *thought* that it works that way. The question still remains the same.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Why does it work as he expects when he types `text` but not `normal`? They should both fail on the first character, and push it back.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The way `scanf` is implemented doesn't really explain why it was implemented that way and why is `no` considered a valid beginning of a float in some circumstance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the C99 spec (7.19.6.2 paras 9 and 12):

> An
>   input item is defined as the longest sequence of input characters which does not exceed
>   any specified field width and which is, or is a prefix of, a matching input sequence.
>   The first character, if any, after the input item remains unread.
>
> **a,e,f,g** Matches an optionally signed floating-point number, infinity, or NaN, whose
>   format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the strtod
>   function.

7.20.1.3 para 3 describes the strtod function:

> The expected form of the subject sequence is an optional plus or minus sign, then one of
>   the following:
>
> - a nonempty sequence of decimal digits optionally containing a decimal-point
>     character, then an optional exponent part as defined in 6.4.4.2;
> - a 0x or 0X, then a nonempty sequence of hexadecimal digits optionally containing a
>     decimal-point character, then an optional binary exponent part as defined in 6.4.4.2;
> - one of INF or INFINITY, ignoring case
> - one of NAN or NAN(n-char-sequence opt ), ignoring case in the NAN part,

para 6 adds

> In other than the "C" locale, additional locale-specific subject sequence forms may be
>   accepted.

This implies that a standard conforming implementation of fscanf, when given `normal` as an input for a `%f` directive, **MUST** consume just the `n` (leaving `ormal` on the input) and fail.  So if your implmentation is also consuming the `o`, then either you're using a non "C" locale that accepts something beginning with `no`, or there would appear to be a bug in the stdlib implementation.

Comment: Locales other than `"C"` are allowed to define other floating-point formats (paragraph 6). While a bug in the stdlib seems likely, it's possible there is some locale-specific floating-point format that includes the prefix `no`

Comment: ... although, having tested it with `LC_ALL=C`, I can confirm that this is a real bug in at least some versions of glibc.

Answer (score 5):

The general answer is that `scanf()` will read one character at a time, and this will go on as long as the characters read might lead to a successful conversion. Only the single character that makes the conversion fail is put back. There's no way in `stdio` `FILE *` streams to put back more than one character anyways.

In your concrete example, it depends on the implementation of your C standard library and what it considers a valid representation of `float`. There are for example implementations that successfully parse strings like `nan` (not a number) or `inf` (infinity). Although I cannot think of a valid `float` representation starting with `no`, your library seems to know one, or it's a bug trying to parse `nan` and not putting back the `o` that makes it fail.

That being said, I can't reproduce this right now on windows using `msvcrt`.

Long story short, better stay away from `scanf()`.

Comment: Nice, not only is it inconsistent, it's **implementation dependant**. Amazing.

Comment: I'm not sure whether parsing `nan` and `inf` is a requirement for `scanf("%f", &f)` ... if it is, `msvcrt` is non-conforming.

Comment: By the way, do you know if `sscanf` sets the byte counter you pass to it the same way as `scanf`? That is will `sscanf(str, "%f%n", &f, &i)` set `i` to `0`, if `sscanf` fails or what? Or is it considered as another target to read and is never reached?

Comment: There is no difference at all regarding how the format string is interpreted, so it will do the same as `scanf()` for `%n`.

Comment: @ruro 1. it is implementation-dependent in the sense that an implementation might be buggy or non-conformant (ms doesn't claim to be c99 conformant). But any interface could be misimplemented; that is not what we usually mean by implementation dependent. 2. If a scanf conversion fails, the scan stops. Period. It will not attempt to do a subsequent `%n` conversion.

Answer (score 2):

I did a quick check and I didn't see any issue:

Platform: Mac

Compiler: GCC

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

$ gcc -Wall main.c

$ ./a.out
Plese input a string or a float.
1.2
B1 1.200000

$ ./a.out
Plese input a string or a float.
100
B1 100.000000

$ ./a.out
Plese input a string or a float.
test
B2 test

$ ./a.out
Plese input a string or a float.
normal
B2 normal        <<<<< No problem here
```

Looks like it is platform dependent.